# hex not evaluating correctly

Tags: objective-c

i tried hard to solve this one on my own but ive spent way to much time on something as simple as this so im hoping someone can give me the answer.
see image below but basically im just trying to get a range built but my marker and my list never meet even though there are items that match the criteria.
in the example below im looking for 2c and the array has it in position 11 but just goes right past it.
[image]

i have tried a few different ways, and the comparison above it works just fine so i dont get where my problem is.
i have tried just  saying

`== 0x2c` (never evaluates)

or using this like i had above

```
`intValue`
```

but this make it get a match on 2D which from my testing is because it truncates the digits down to just plain 2.

ACTUAL CODE:

```
int lastIndexInPayload = ([payload count]-1);
            int beginningOfData = ([payload count]-1);
            NSString * endOfLine = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X", 0x0D];
            NSString * startOfLine = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X", 0x2C];

             if ([[payload objectAtIndex:lastIndexInPayload]intValue]  == [endOfLine intValue]) {

                 while ([payload objectAtIndex:beginningOfData]!= startOfLine) {
                     beginningOfData--;
                     DDLogVerbose(@"beginningOfData %d",beginningOfData);

                 }
            }
```

the payload is an array of bytes
taken from nsdata from a socket return

Comment: Please post the actual code, not just pictures of it. The pic of the debugger helps, but it helps us to copy/correct/paste the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine it's because you're using `==` to compare objects. Since it appears both your array and your `startOfLine` object are just hex strings representing a single byte, you should probably just use `-isEqualToString:`, as in

```
while (![[payload objectAtIndex:beginningOfData] isEqualToString:startOfLine]) {
```

That said, I find it rather odd that your payload is an array of hex bytes represented as strings. Why not just shove the whole thing into an NSData and have access to "real" bytes instead?

Comment: @owengerig: Two objects which are equal, in this case two strings, are not necessarily the same object pointer. You'd have the same problem if you were working with `char*`. Two `char*`'s which `strcmp()` says are identical may nevertheless be separate pointers to separate blocks of memory that contain the same contents. As a general rule, `==` is useless on Obj-C objects unless you really, truly want to know if it's the exact same object (as opposed to merely being equal).

Comment: thank you.  i had been working on this so much i got lost as some point in time.  but i figured it was because i had an object (return from object at index) and was trying to see if it equaled the string object.  thats why i had ventured into intValue, stringValue and the likes.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing strings according to their address and not their contents, you should use `while (![[payload objectAtIndex:beginningOfData] isEqualToString:startOfLine])`. Also why are you trying to use strings for hex values and not just compare against `0xD` directly? Your call to intValue will result in `0` for endOfLine because it does not know that it is hex and will stop trying to parse a number.

Comment: when i put 0x2c vs startofline i get a bad exec error.  u can see from my other conditional statements i did that and it worked.  i mark this up though because it does answer the why (address and not content) which is kinda what i figured but couldnt grasp

Comment: i would think thats because 0x2c isnt a string its a number